# Example of Spherical Element (Simplicial Homotopy)

Tags: algebraic-topology, simplicial-stuff

Definition: An element $x\in X_n$ is said to be spherical if $d_i x=*$ for all $0\leq i\leq n$. $X$ is a pointed fibrant simplicial set.

I am puzzling over this definition.

For instance, if $x=(x_0,x_1,\dots,x_n)$, then $d_i x=(x_0,\dots,x_{i-1},x_{i+1},\dots,x_n)$ is firstly different for each $i$, and secondly comprised of $n$ components so it can't possibly be the basepoint $*$?

Is there any concrete example of such a spherical element $x$?

Comment: Could you point out your definition of pointed simplicial set? There are at least two that come to my mind.

Comment: I missed out the key word "fibrant" or Kan complex.  So $X$ is a simplicial set with a choice of a basepoint, it is also fibrant (Kan complex).

Comment: @GiorgioMossa I'm curious, I can think of two definitions (either every $X_n$ is pointed and the simplicial structure maps are pointed, or there is a morphism of simplicial sets from the constant one to $X$, i.e. $* \to X$), but both are equivalent. What were you thinking of?

Comment: I see, let me be more clear about my doubt. The problem lies in the notion of point you want to use: by point do you mean an element of $X_0$ (that is a $0$-simplex) or a morphism from $1$ (the terminal simplicial set) into $X$?

Comment: @NajibIdrissi if you like you could think them as two different kind of slice-categories one is the canonical $1/\mathbf{sSet}$, where $1$ is the terminal presheaf, the other one is $S^{0}/\mathbf{sSet}$, where $S^{0}$ represent the simplicial set where $S^{0}_0$ is a singleton and each $S^0_n$ is empty for $n > 0$.

Comment: @GiorgioMossa I don't understand what you simplicial set $S^0$ is. What is $s_0 : S^0_0 = \{*\} \to S^0_1 = \varnothing$? In any case, $\Delta^0$ is the terminal object in $\mathsf{sSet}$, and $\hom_{\mathsf{sSet}}(\Delta^0, X) \cong X_0$...

Comment: @NajibIdrissi is the simplicial set with only one $0$-simplex and no simplex in higher dimension. Clearly this cannot be a the terminal simplicial set.

Comment: @GiorgioMossa I really don't understand what you say... $\Delta^0$ has only one *nondegenerate* 0-simplex, and it has no *nondegenerate* simplexes in higher dimensions, but it *has* degenerate simplexes in higher dimension.

Comment: @GiorgioMossa This is not a simplicial set. The image of the 0-simplex w.r.t. the degeneracies gives you higher simplices. Najib Idrissi is right, the two definitions are equivalent.

Comment: AAAAAAAH Sorry I forgot you have degeracy maps in $\Delta$, so stupid by me. Again apologize for the confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like the question arises from two points of confusion.

1) If you think of * as an element of $X_0$, then you need to remember that an element of $X_0$ gives rise, via the degeneracy maps, to an element in each $X_n$.  (Play around with the simplicial identities to see why you get a well-defined element in $X_n$, regardless of which degeneracy maps you compose to get from $X_0$ up to $X_n$.)

2) In a simplicial set, elements in $X_n$ are not uniquely determined by a list of vertices. And there is nothing preventing two faces of a simplex from being the same. In this question, the relevant point is that for some simplices, all faces are the same! Think of a triangle in which all three vertices have been glued together into one point. You can even go a step further and collapse all three edges onto that same point. Now you have a sphere!

Comment: Thanks! I think I am starting to get it. So if $x$ is spherical, all the vertices and edges of $x$ are identified into a single point? By your answer that is a sufficient condition, is it also a necessary condition?

Comment: For #1, if you don't want to play with the simplicial identities, notice that any combination of degeneracies $X_0 \to X_n$ is the image of a map from $\hom_\Delta([n], [0])$, but $[0] = \{0\}$ is a singleton so there is only one map $[n] \to [0]$.

Comment: @yoyostein: that is essentially a rephrasing of the definition of "spherical". The definition states that each maximal face of x (that is, d_i x) is equal to the basepoint * (which, again, really means d_0 d_0 ... d_0(*) if * lies in X_0).  But then if you take any face of * you just get * again, so any sequence of face maps applied to a spherical element results in the basepoint.